# Draining of SQS Queue using Lambda after a certain days

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

So, I am putting some entries in SQS Queue which is set as an event source for the Lambda, and this flow is working fine. As soon as entry comes in SQS queue lambda process it. so far so good.

But I have a situation where I want to let the entries to stay in SQS for 3-4 days and then let a lambda process them.

So basically if I see that okey, I have 100 entries in my SQS Queue and it's been 4 days now. I want to let lambda drain them and run some logic. Is this possible, Kindly guide me?

Comment: Not possible directly with SQS. The `DelaySeconds` parameter of the `SendMessage` API supports values only up to 15 seconds. You need much more than that. One possibility is to use Step Functions, and then include a `Wait` state — it can be configured to wait up to 1 year.

Comment: Amazon tech support guys told to disable the lambda and then enable after 4 days.

Comment: Well, then you already have a solution, don't you? It's probably a good idea for you to edit your question and mention it and explain why it doesn't work. If it does work, then you can answer your own question and accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Will do :)

Answer (score 1):

I think disabling lambda is not the way to fulfil the requirement, as you will miss other messages too.

SQS is messaging service and when it integrated with Lambda you can just configure retry and process the message, keeping the message in SQS, not in user control but lambda do that by design.

> Lambda polls the queue and invokes your function synchronously with an
> event that contains queue messages. Lambda reads messages in batches
> and invokes your function once for each batch. **When your function
> successfully processes a batch, Lambda deletes its messages from the
> queue.**

[enter link description here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html)

One solution that can work to deal with your query

> But I have a situation where I want to let the entries to stay in SQS
> for 3-4 days and then let a lambda process them.

You also need to decide which SQS should not be processed at the moment and push these message to DynamoDb and then process these message after 4 or 5 days base on Dynamo DB [TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) that was added during insertion. You can follow below steps

- Add property to SQS is_dynamodb to identify the message that should not be processed at the moment
- Push such message to DynamoDB
- Add TTL during insertion
- Check event in Lambda function that stream from DynamoDb is **removed** not insertion
- Process messages if the event is Removed

[image: Arctecture Diagram]